# Increase robustness of 7z LZMA archiving?

Tags: backup, compression, 7-zip, archiving

I create backups of several PHP projects like Wordpress etc, which contain a huge amount of small files. Hence I zip them into one archive to make transfering and checking the file easier / faster. I do not care too much about the added compression, it's nice to have, but it's mainly as described for purpose of Filesync benefits.

A few years ago I still used WinRar and there was an option to embed "restore information" (in percent of the overall resulting filesize). Nowadays, I use 7z with LZMA2 compression, using "Normal" compression rate. But I cant find such an option to embed restore information. Is this "feature" outdated or obsolete or does 7z simply not support it?

What do you think - is it therefore better to stick with WinRar or is LZMA2 in general more robust when it comes to data corruption, so that single files can still be recovered / extracted? I want to avoid that the whole archive becomes corrupt completely...

Or is it sufficient if I deactivate "solid" archiving and instead use "non-solid"?

Thanks so muh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repair files after corruption, one can generate [par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) files. These "parity" files use error correction codes, and can be used to correct errors anywhere in the file they are created for (where the number of errors fixed is limited by the amount of parity data), similar to [WinRAR recovery volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_archivers#endnote_features-WinRAR).

This is not a valid substitute for the 3-2-1 rule, and should ideally be used in conjunction with it to further reduce the risk of data loss or to increase convenience.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that PAR files are a generic concept for error correction, independently from archives or whatever - means: I could generate such a PAR file wherever I want? And further: Is my understanding correct that WinRAR internally uses such a PAR mechanism if one selects to embed restore information with the archive?

Comment: @tim: Yes, PAR2 are an implementation of error correction that is independent of archives; one could generate par2 files for pictures, encrypted data, etc. And it would seem so, yes, that WinRAR uses a mechanism similar to that of PAR2 to create a degree of redundancy in the resulting archive.

Comment: Great, thanks, that helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

By design 7z do not permit you definition of recovery records. And AFAIK this do not depend of the compression algorithm. Just create more often backups and use the rule 3-2-1:

> ```
> 3: Create one primary backup and two copies of your data.
> 2: Save your backups to two different types of media.
> 1: Keep at least one backup file offsite.
> ```

For more info check [here](https://www.uschamber.com/co/run/technology/3-2-1-backup-rule)

Comment: Even with 3,2,1 you could still get one bit flip copied to all three versions, it you're really unlucky. I'd still go with RAR/PAR & then 3,2,1 - belt & braces.

Comment: @Tetsujin, you are right :) But probability of bit flip is veeeery small, it is on power of 3. Moreover in 7z there is 1% recovery block (AFAIK) so you may recover most of files and get missing from old archive. Again the probability bit flip in exactly last changed files become even smaller :D. You know, it is balance between effort, time and money.

Comment: Well, I didnt know 7z wouldnt be able to do that. So is WinRar in this sense really better, my understanding correct? And my question about solid archiving: Is it like that, that selecting "non-solid" would be helpful a bit in recovering files from an archive?

Comment: @tim, AFAIK solid archive offer better compression, but you can't update it postfactum. If you create new archive every time and do not need to add/remove files use solid archives.

Comment: ??? Im not asking because of better compression but because of better recovery methods... See my original post. So I guess your comment is off in this case

Comment: @tim, I am not aware compression in solid archive to add additional recovery information.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to increase the robustness of LZMA is to turn off solid archives.  Then if there is a bad checksum the issue would be localized to the file, instead of ruining the whole archive.  But you would still not be able to repair/recover that file with 7zip itself; it would just limit the damage.

With WinRar, the repair functionality is built-in, if you were looking to just use 1 tool.  Or with 7-zip + a Parchive app, you'd be able to repair also but you'd need that second app as 7-zip [doesn't currently include](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/609c0cebd9/) that functionality.